# Ruby Mechanize ASP webpage

Tags: asp.net, ruby, mechanize

I am trying to mimic filling out a form using `Mechanize`. But, it is an ASP webpage and even though I think I am handling the doPostbacks correctly I am still getting an error using information that works fine when I manually fill in the page (the error is the page saying it is 'currently undergoing routine maintenance', which must be happening because I am missing a required param).

When I submit the form manually this is the request made to the server (as found in the Network tab of the Chrome Inspector tool):

```
Remote Address:209.67.234.13:80
Request URL:http://www.luckystarbus.com/Purchase.aspx
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview parsed
POST /Purchase.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.luckystarbus.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3450
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://www.luckystarbus.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://www.luckystarbus.com/Purchase.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=2mw5a43zz43nemyj5e4glq45; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.181151250.1412747640
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__LASTFOCUS:
__VIEWSTATE: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
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:C7C53EDD
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWNwKs4av/BwLuseWwCgLV3sKgCwKn3JGKDQLJj5y8CgLIj5y8CgLLj5y8CgLKj5y8CgLNj5y8CgLMj5y8CgLPj5y8CgLej5y8CgLRj5y8CgLJj9y/CgLJj9C/CgLJj9S/CgLJj+i/CgLJj+y/CgLJj+C/CgLJj+S/CgLJj/i/CgLJj7y8CgLJj7C8CgLIj9y/CgLIj9C/CgLIj9S/CgLIj+i/CgLIj+y/CgLIj+C/CgLIj+S/CgLIj/i/CgLIj7y8CgLIj7C8CgLLj9y/CgLLj9C/CgLLj9S/CgLLj+i/CgLLj+y/CgLLj+C/CgLLj+S/CgLLj/i/CgLLj7y8CgLLj7C8CgLKj9y/CgKEqZSECQKEqZSECQKu98XRCAKppL+gBwKztP72DgKw7NHHAgLe4cH0AgLmvYqoAgLczuTwCAKkgd7NDALA6+GiC77wn7OOuuAuAIz5dzZgP6GxLs9S
ctl00$MainContent$rbTripType:One
ctl00$MainContent$numPassengers:1
ctl00$MainContent$ddDepartureCity:Boston, MA
ctl00$MainContent$ddArrivalCity:1
ctl00$MainContent$sd:10/17/2014
ctl00$MainContent$rbFareType:Lowest
ctl00$MainContent$btGo.x:64
ctl00$MainContent$btGo.y:13
```

So, I tried to mimic each of these inputs using Mechanize:

```
def search
  agent = Mechanize.new
  url = "http://www.luckystarbus.com"
  page = agent.get(url)
  form = page.form("aspnetForm")
  form.radiobutton_with(value: 'One').check
  form.field_with(name: 'ctl00$MainContent$ddDepartureCity').options[1].select
  form.add_field!('__EVENTARGUMENT', '')
  form.add_field!('__EVENTTARGET', '')
  form.add_field!('__LASTFOCUS', '')
  form.add_field!('ctl00$MainContent$btGo.x',64)
  form.add_field!('ctl00$MainContent$btGo.y',13)
  form.field_with(name: 'ctl00$MainContent$sd').value = "10/24/2014"
  form.radiobutton_with(value: 'Lowest').check
  page = form.click_button
end
```

I also attempted to post the params as suggested by another SO answer but got the same error:

```
def search
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.post("http://www.luckystarbus.com/Purchase.aspx", {
    'ctl00$MainContent$rbTripType'=>'One',
    'ctl00$MainContent$numPassengers'=>'1',
    'ctl00$MainContent$ddArrivalCity'=>'New%20York%2C+NY',
    'ctl00$MainContent$ddDepartureCity'=>'Boston%2C+MA',
    'ctl00$MainContent$sd'=>'10%2F24%2F2014',
    'ctl00$MainContent$rbFareType'=>'Lowest',
    'ctl00$MainContent$btGo.x'=>64,
    'ctl00$MainContent$btGo.y'=>13,
    '__EVENTARGUMENT'=>'',
    '__EVENTTARGET'=>'',
    '__LASTFOCUS'=>''
    })
end
```

The page I'm trying to get back should have the title 'Choose Schedule'. Is there a method I am missing when submitting the params directly this way? Should I be performing a `form.click_button` each time an input with a doPostback is filled in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the doPostBack values if they're required.
Let's say the form has:

```
<form onsubmit="doPostback('foo', 'bar')">
```

Then for mechanize you would do:

```
form['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'foo'
form['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = 'bar'
```

If you still can't get it, make the request in your browser and pull the values from there:

```
page = @agent.get 'http://www.luckystarbus.com/'
form = page.form

form['ctl00$MainContent$rbTripType'] = 'One'
form['ctl00$MainContent$numPassengers'] = '1'
form['ctl00$MainContent$ddDepartureCity'] = 'Boston, MA'
form['ctl00$MainContent$ddArrivalCity'] = '1'
form['ctl00$MainContent$sd'] = '10/17/2014'
form['ctl00$MainContent$rbFareType'] = 'Lowest'

form['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$MainContent$rbTripType$1'
form['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ''
form['__VIEWSTATE'] = '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'
form['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = '/wEWNwKf77e6AwLuseWwCgLV3sKgCwKn3JGKDQLJj5y8CgLIj5y8CgLLj5y8CgLKj5y8CgLNj5y8CgLMj5y8CgLPj5y8CgLej5y8CgLRj5y8CgLJj9y/CgLJj9C/CgLJj9S/CgLJj+i/CgLJj+y/CgLJj+C/CgLJj+S/CgLJj/i/CgLJj7y8CgLJj7C8CgLIj9y/CgLIj9C/CgLIj9S/CgLIj+i/CgLIj+y/CgLIj+C/CgLIj+S/CgLIj/i/CgLIj7y8CgLIj7C8CgLLj9y/CgLLj9C/CgLLj9S/CgLLj+i/CgLLj+y/CgLLj+C/CgLLj+S/CgLLj/i/CgLLj7y8CgLLj7C8CgLKj9y/CgKEqZSECQKEqZSECQKu98XRCAKppL+gBwKztP72DgKw7NHHAgLe4cH0AgLmvYqoAgLczuTwCAKkgd7NDALA6+GiC9RzJOOGhIrLnJW1ydqt1vZKIsKV'
form['ctl00$MainContent$btGo.x'] = 0
form['ctl00$MainContent$btGo.y'] = 0

page = form.submit
```

works for me.

Comment: I tried this but it's not the form itself that has the doPostBack it's specific inputs on the form. So, when the roundtrip option is selected it performs a doPostback, as well as when the departure city is selected. In the browser the page automatically submits when I set these things but with Mechanize it doesn't seem to do the page reload and I can't set the EVENTTARGET twice because that will overwrite the previous value.

Comment: Whatever the last doPostBack is is what the values should be. Try using a debugging proxy like charles or fiddler to see what those values are.

Comment: Using Chrome's Inspector tools I can see the request and headers sent to the server, I provided values for each one of those values and the form is still returning an error.

Comment: This still returns the original 'Purchase eTicket' page instead of the 'Choose Schedule' page (you can see it in the title attribute)

Comment: Hmm, try putting Go.x and Go.y back in. That should do it.

Comment: Specifically for me, I needed `btnGo2.x` and `btnGo2.y` fields. I fixed them for testing (so they matched my VCR cassettes) and randomized them otherwise. Just because.

`form["btnGo2.x"] = Rails.env.test? ? 31 : rand(10..40)` and `form["btnGo2.y"] = Rails.env.test? ? 10 : rand(10..40)`